# Install Matplot Lib Mac - Mavericks - Error pyplot

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have tried installing matplotlib a number of ways and I was successful using - download through github, changing directory to folder, and running sudo python setup.py install. But, pyplot wasn't working so I uninstalled and I am trying to use pip and have been running into a ton of errors.

```
Megans-MacBook-Pro:~ MeganRCunninghan$ sudo pip install matplotlib
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.4.0]
                    python: yes [2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)  [GCC
                            4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.6.2]
                       six: yes [six was not found.]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 1.5]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                            mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                     pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build/matplotlib/setup.py", line 154, in <module>
        result = package.check()
      File "setupext.py", line 940, in check
        if 'No such file or directory\ngrep:' in version:
    TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options



BUILDING MATPLOTLIB

            matplotlib: yes [1.4.0]

                python: yes [2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)  [GCC

                        4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]]

              platform: yes [darwin]



REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS

                 numpy: yes [version 1.6.2]

                   six: yes [six was not found.]

              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 1.5]

               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the

                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to

                        install it after matplotlib.]

             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for

                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to

                        install it after matplotlib.]

                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]

                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not

                        be found. Using local copy.]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build/matplotlib/setup.py", line 154, in <module>

    result = package.check()

  File "setupext.py", line 940, in check

    if 'No such file or directory\ngrep:' in version:

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/matplotlib
Storing complete log in /Users/MeganRCunninghan/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

when I go to python and I type

```
>>import matplot lib
```

it works but when I want matplotlib.pyplot I get an error:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem:
Uninstalled matplotlib manually by located install directory in python:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__file__
```

Then I went to my finder and located the folder using CMD+Shift+G and pasted the file location given.
Selected the matplotlib file  and deleted.
Went to cmd line and typed

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Now it works.
Also, before running pip I installed xcode and fixed the hang up between clang and lipo as well using these instructions:
Install xcode, go to termina -

```
 xcode-select --install
```

Install Command Line tools at: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools#

Go to terminal:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/lipo /usr/bin/lipo.orig sudo 
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lipo /usr/bin
```

Install Pip if you dont have it:

```
sudo su 
easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you install [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). It solves a lot of the issues that comes up when installing scientific related modules.

Comment: thanks! I fixed the issue, but I will check this out for future issues. :)